# How to find out if this function is characteristic

Tags: probability-theory, characteristic-functions

I need to find out if $\phi$ is a characteristic function

$$
\phi(t_1,t_2) = (p\cos(t_1+t_2) + 1 - p)^n, \quad 0 < p < 1, n \in \mathbb{N_{>0}}
$$

What I've tried:

1. Instead I'm trying to prove that $p\cos(t_1+t_2) + 1 - p$ is characteristic because if it is then it's n-th power also is characteristic.
2. I've tried converting $\cos$ to trig form and then doing Fourier transform to get p.d.f. and got
   $$
   p \pi \delta_{x-1} \delta_{y-1} + 
   p \pi \delta_{x+1} \delta_{y+1} + 
   2 \pi \delta_{x} \delta_{y} + 
   2 p \pi \delta_{x} \delta_{y}
   $$
   but I'm not sure if this is a p.d.f.
3. Also, $\phi$ looks like a characteristic function of $Bin(n,p)$:
   $$
   {\displaystyle \!\,(1-p+pe^{it})^{n}}
   $$
   but I don't know if there is any connection between them.

Comment: As a warm-up, is $t\mapsto \cos(t)$ a characteristic function?

Comment: Sure. $P(X=-1)=P(X=1)=\frac{1}{2}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the right hunch.
You can check the characteristic function of the following random variable:
$$X=(B_1+...+B_n,B_1+...B_n)$$
where $B,B_1,...,B_n$ are iid random variables, B equals 0 with probability 1-p, B equals 1 with probability p/2, -1 with probability p/2

Comment: Hm. I've tried doing that for a smaller case of $X = (B_1, B_1)$.
And got a function $\phi(t_1,t_2) = 1 - p + pe^{i(t_1+t_2)}$. Which is close but still not it...

Comment: youre right. We need to modify more. Im not with my laptop now, ill update later

Comment: @ilia  i updated my answer

Comment: That's it. Thanks!